# Relationship in android Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, tags, relation

Please I really need your help, I'm implementing an app with tagging feature just like twitter. I'm using parse.com and I have a class Photo and class Tag. So the user write the tag name in the text field and when the user click the upload photo button a relation created between the 2 classes, so when I click a tag, all the photo tagged with that tag will be displayed.

```
   upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Photo");
            query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(final ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        final ParseObject tag= new ParseObject("Tags");
                        tag.put("tag_name", addName.getText().toString());

                        final ParseObject photo = new ParseObject("Photo");

                        photo.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    ParseRelation relation = tag.getRelation("photo");
                                    relation.add(photo);
                                    tag.saveInBackground();
                                }
                            }
                        });
        }
    });
```

any suggestions will be appreciated <3

Comment: Why are you asking us to guess if your code is wrong? Test it

Comment: I mean the way I wrote the code .. but the code is wrong !

Comment: @Wain is right. You are creating a new Tag object each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly creating a new tag each time. Instead of doing that you should be querying for the tags with the same name and connecting them or creating new ones if you don't find any matches.

Comment: Can you show me some quick snippets of the code .. I can't find good tutorials and I don't find parse.com is enough :(

Comment: You have a query for photo, it's the same thing for tags

Comment: Not clear why you're also creating a new photo after querying for a photo... It seems you don't really understand the difference between finding existing and creating new?

Comment: So you need to break things down into parts, solve each then build up. Query for tags for the entered text first and log the result. Then work on testing the result to see if you get matches, then create when there isn't one. Do one piece at a time.